# TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable with apply lambda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to apply a condition to a column in my pandas dataframe, but i get this error :
 

 
`TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`

```
Cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22.000,25.000,27.000,35.000]
        }

Cars = DataFrame(Cars, columns= ['Brand', 'Price'])
```

```
Cars ['Price'] = Cars ['Price'].apply(lambda x: [0 if y <= 25.000 else 1 for y in x])
```

Any thoughts ?

Comment: With `apply`, the argument to the function is a single element of the container.  In other words, instead of `lambda x: [0 if y <= 25.000 else 1 for y in x]`, you just want `lambda x: 0 if x <= 25.000 else 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `apply` is bad choice, because there are loops under the hood, so slow in large data. Better is use vectorized solutions with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
Cars ['Price'] = np.where(Cars ['Price'] <= 25.000, 0, 1)
```

Or `innvert` condition to `>` and cast to `integer` for `True/False` to `0/1` mapping:

```
Cars ['Price'] = (Cars ['Price'] > 25.000).astype(int)
```

---

```
print (Cars)

            Brand  Price
0     Honda Civic      0
1  Toyota Corolla      0
2      Ford Focus      1
3         Audi A4      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't iterate through the list, `.apply` [applies the function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to **each** element in the column!

Try this line:

`Cars ['Price'] = Cars ['Price'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x <= 25.000 else 1)`

Comment: My bad I interpreted wrong the definition of .apply